# Handle nested ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie in `Angular js`. Trying to use `ng-repeat` in following way

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "rajeev", "sandeep","deepak"];
});

<div class="dynamicTile" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div id="{{ 'tile' + $index }}" class="tile" ng-repeat="x in names">
                <h1>myNewTile</h1>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It gives me structure like this

```
myNewTile
myNewTile
myNewTile
myNewTile
myNewTile
```

I wanna every `row` contain only `two tiles`. For `third and fourth` tile new `row` should be created and so on. something like this

```
myNewTile   myNewTile
myNewTile   myNewTile
myNewTile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

## First Solution

Just put the `ng-repeat` in your column `div`:

```
<div class="dynamicTile" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="x in names">
            <div id="{{ 'tile' + $index }}" class="tile">
              <h1>myNewTile</h1>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Bootstrap will take care of the rest.

## OR Second Solution

The problem with the first solution will arise when the height of each columns are not same due to the content then the Bootstrap will not be able to perform proper alignment of the columns. So you can either use this one.

You can first collate your list and the put two `ng-repeat` inside there:

```js
// An helper function to collate the list 
Array.prototype.collate = function(size) {
  var list = [];

  angular.forEach(this, function(item, i) {
    if (i % size === 0) {
      list[Math.floor(i / size)] = [item];
    } else {
      list[Math.floor(i / size)].push(item);
    }
  });

  return list;
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "rajeev", "sandeep", "deepak"];
  $scope.collatedNames = names.collate(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dynamicTile" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="names in collatedNames">
    <div class="col-xs-6" ng-repeat="x in names">
      <div id="{{ 'tile' + $index }}" class="tile">
        <h1>myNewTile</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```